# How to use an emergency button for an SSR controlling 3kW heaters

Tags: solid-state-relay, pid-controller, heater

I'm working on a temperature control project for airflow utilizing a 3kW heater, an SSR, and a PID controller.

For safety purposes, I need to incorporate an emergency button to immediately cut off power to the heaters. I plan to use a push button, which essentially operates as a simple switch, to interrupt the command signal between the PID and SSR.

My concern is whether this setup will function as intended. Will the SSR deactivate power if it doesn't receive a command signal? I've attempted to find clarification in the equipment guide without success.

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Just curious. Why not break access to the power source using the emergency switch? This would seem to the more direct approach. Another approach would be to consider the conditions under which the emergency button is required. If it is a matter of temperature, you can design into the system (through physics itself) a way that the temperature directly impacts the system and self-limits. But that is a different approach and may involve changing the heater design, itself. (Study Freeman Dyson & Edward Teller design work on **TRIGA** for an approach here.)

Comment: Emergency Switch! For safety, it must be as foolproof as possible. What if the SSR fails. You need to interrupt the power at the source. https://media.distributordatasolutions.com/siemenscomplete/2023q3/documents/889e5f833e1d330b56df5202edab076cd69f206a.pdf

Comment: This question could use an update, what is the model numbers? Can you post a block diagram

Answer (score 2):

Damaged SSRs can fail short (see page 6 of: https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/precautions_ssr.pdf). For that reason alone, you should break the heater circuit on the power side, not the signal side. Leakage current could also be a factor.

Answer (score 0):

Probability of the SSR failing short necessitates the use of a 'heater contactor' with 'On', 'Off' and 'Latched Em Off' push button switches.

Here's the schematic.

[image]